# Flashing listBox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, client-server

i want to know if it's possible to flash listbox.
I'm creating a chat application (client-server) with c# and winform and i want to make my listbox flash when i receive a new message.
It's possible ? thank you

Comment: Did you try anything yet? How about setting the background colour to something dark for a couple of hundred milliseconds?

Comment: yes, it's can be a good idea, thanks man !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var originalColor = listBox1.BackgroundColor;
listBox1.BackgroundColor = Color.LightYellow;
await Task.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100));
listBox1.BackgroundColor = originalColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi "Flash" mean Clear?

How to: Add and Clear Items in a ListBox Control
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228375(v=vs.90).aspx

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.Items.Add("Sally");
   listBox1.Items.Add("Craig");
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   listBox1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: no sorry, i wan't to flash like light :) not clearing